# Return from an anonymous immediately invoked function expression | Where does it go?

Tags: javascript

If I return an object from an anonymous immediately invoked function expression where does it go? For example where does foo go in this code....

```
(function(){ 
    var foo;
    return foo;
})();
```

Does this have any useful applications?

Comment: It's not different from calling a "normal" function `bar();` and not doing anything with the return value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Returning a value from your self-executing function without assigning that return value to a result variable is just a return value that goes nowhere and thus creates no new references to the data in your function.  So as soon as the function returns, the data will be garbage collected, the same as if you didn't have the return statement.  So, this:

```
(function(){ 
    var foo;
    return foo;
})();
```

is no different than returning a value from a function and not assigning the returned value to anything.

You would do this to capture the return value:

```
var result = (function(){ 
    var foo = "hello";
    return foo;
})();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/t9wJL/

---

As for the usefulness of returning a value.  It's useful if you assign the return value to a variable or use it as input into some other function, but accomplishes nothing if you don't.

Comment: interesting that the language will allow you to do non-sensical(memory-wasting) things w/ no erorrs.  Got to wonder if jslint would catch this.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - It's not memory wasting and causes no problems.  It wastes the execution of one line of code - that's it for the consequences.  The garbage collector cleans it up whatever is in `foo` at the same time that it's cleaned up if you don't return it.

Comment: GC is done periodically...so technically it will waste memory until the next GC collection.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - you don't seem to understand.  The memory is already allocated by having the variable in your function.  No additional memory is consumed because you return it.  So returning it and not using it has no affect on the amount of memory consumed.  It gets garbage collected at the same time whether it's returned from the function or not.  There is no difference in memory use when you return it.

Comment: That is true...foo has been allocated...when you return it...you return a reference to it....actually you have to save that reference some where I would imagine...I still think you have a saved reference somewhere that otherwise you would not have...but just guessing.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - if it isn't assigned anywhere after the return value, then no new reference is created.  A reference is only created when some other variable actually holds a reference to the data.  When the function finishes, there will be exactly zero references remaining to `foo` whether you returned it or not.

Comment: I'm sorry then...in your answer...what are you saying gets garbage collected then...specefically?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - OK, I've clarified the wording in my answer.

Comment: well i didn't know JS people cared about memory

Answer (score 3):

A useful application is in feature testing. E.g. some browsers support the *textContent* property, some support *innerText* and some support both. I could write a function that tests for support and uses the appropriate property:

```
function getText(el) {

  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    return el.textContent;

  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    return el.innerText;
  }
}
```

You might feel that doing the same test every time is inefficient (not by much) so you might like to detect support and create a function that does the test just once and thereafter uses an appropriate property, e.g.:

```
var getText = (function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');

  if (typeof el.textContent == 'string') {
    el = null;
    return function (el) { return el.textContent;};

  } else if (typeof el.innerText == 'string') {
    el = null;
    return function (el) { return el.innerText;};
  }
}());
```

The above functions are a little flawed, they're just examples.

Note that the opening and closing brackets can be omitted, however having them helps when reading the code, you know it's an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE) from the very first line rather than somewhere in the middle or at the end.

The primary benefit is being able to run some code with out creating unnecessary global references and then having to clean them up. The above example creates a closure (to `el`) between the returned function and the IIFE, so it may not be garbage collected until the page us unloaded unless the compiler is clever enough to know that the closure isn't being used.

Closures are consequence of using IIFEs this way, but it's an insignificant issue unless the IFFE is huge and the closures are wasteful (in many cases they are useful).

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of the self-executing function is to create a new scope then returning something makes no sense. If the function is being assigned to a variable then the returned value would be assigned to it.

```
var foo = (function(){ return 'foo' }()); // this makes sense
```

Comment: The purpose of a an immediately invoked function expression might be to immediately invoke a function without creating a lingering function object. The scope aspect is an unavoidable side effect that might be useful, or be a hindrance.

Answer (score 1):

The foo is returned as a result of the function being executed. It will only 'exist' if it is assigned to a variable or passed to another function:

```
var x = (function(){ 
    var foo;
    return foo;
})();
console.log(x)
```

Does that help?